# How to show Geo-location permission prompt in android webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

When I tried to load this http://m.jetcharters.com/app/ URL in the browser it show a prompt for getting user permission. But when I tried to load it into android WebView, it can't show prompt. So I tried to manually show a prompt using this method:

```
 public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    showAPromptMessage();
 }
```

But the problem is that, I have to load data based on user sharing or denying location. Suppose that if user share location I will load **www.google.com** on the other-hand I will load **www.yahoo.com**. How can I implement this situation without hampering user concentration?